# R output to JSON get "_row" : in objects

Tags: json, r, rest, api

I'm trying to interact with a rest API using R. I want to be able convert from JSON and then back into JSON in the same format. But; from the JSON:
(excerpt)

```
  "access": {
"read": true,
"update": true,
"externalize": false,
"delete": true,
"write": true,
"manage": true
```

I run :

```
 df<-jsonlite::fromJSON(r)
```

And get back a df with columns:

```
access.read TRUE
access.update TRUE
(etc)
```

When i then run it back:

```
df <- jsonlite::toJSON(df)
```

I get either:

```
        "access": {
        "read": true,
        "update": true,
        "externalize": false,
        "delete": true,
        "write": true,
        "manage": true,
        "_row": "1"
    },
```

See bottom line _row, which corrupts my PUT back into REST.

Or, if I append df <- jsonlite::toJSON(df, flatten=TRUE)

I get:

```
        "access.read": true,
    "access.update": true,
    "access.externalize": false,
    "access.delete": true,
    "access.write": true,
    "access.manage": true,
```

Which doesn't seem to read/import very well into my REST Api.

Any suggestions for how to fix this? I can't seem to find anything googling this issue..

Thanks!

Comment: Try with `names(df) <- NA`, before this line `df <- jsonlite::toJSON(df)`...or try something like `df <- jsonlite::toJSON(unname(df), pretty = T)`

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't work. Using unname(df) makes all the column names dissapear, just giving: 
"
 true,
 true,
 false,
 true,
 true,
 true,
"

Answer (score 4):

Try...

```
back_to_JSON <- jsonlite::toJSON(df, rownames = FALSE)
```

The `toJSON()` function in the `jsonlite` package doesn't have any documentation on this behavior. However, viewing the code shows that it uses `asJSON()` under the hood.

The source code for the S3 method `asJSON.data.frame` is on [github](https://github.com/jeroen/jsonlite/blob/a68e1d46e2ae6450cd46c12be0e32fd66d12a90c/R/asJSON.data.frame.R#L14). As of the time this is written, lines 14-21 address this issue. Using the `...` in your `toJSON()` call will pass the `rownames = FALSE` parameter down and this will fix your problem.